# Dynamic Table Change jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, onchange

I have managed to get a table to change dynamically pulling data from a json file depending on the value of a select drop down.

I want it to load however with a default value - in this case 2017

There is no table when the page first loads.

Thanks

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function (){

  //Code below here is to dynamically change the table

    let url = "students.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function(response){

    //   The default value should be the value of the 
        let entryYear = "2017";

        // code here is to record the change of the dropdown button
          $("select.year").change(function(){
              entryYear = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

        //setup the table
             let tableHTML = '<table>\
                                <tr>\
                                    <th>Firstname</th>\
                                    <th>Entry year</th>\
                                </tr>';

        //for each of the records in the json file
        //identify the students
        $.each(response, function(index, student){
         //identify the students who started in 2018
        //  https://www.formget.com/dynamically-change-form-action-based-on-selection-using-jquery/
         if (student.entry_year === entryYear){

             tableHTML +='<tr>\
                            <td>'+student.name+'</td>\
                            <td>'+student.entry_year+'</td>\
                          </tr>';
         } 
        }

        );//end each

        //close the table tag
        tableHTML += '</table>';

        // add the data pulled to the html of the page in the div dynamic table 
        $('#dynamicTable').html(tableHTML);
     }); //end .change
    });// end json

}); //end ready
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <select class="year">
        <option value="2017" selected="selected">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="dynamicTable">
  <!-- the dynamic table will go in here-->
</div>
```

The .change works when altering the drop down but the initial page load produces no table

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a function that generates the table and just pass it the year.

In my example, I call the function on change, but I also have it outside any event so that it processes on page ready.

```js
$.create_table = function(entryYear){
let url = "students.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function(response){

        //setup the table
             let tableHTML = '<table>\
                                <tr>\
                                    <th>Firstname</th>\
                                    <th>Entry year</th>\
                                </tr>';

        //for each of the records in the json file
        //identify the students
        $.each(response, function(index, student){
         //identify the students who started in 2018
        //  https://www.formget.com/dynamically-change-form-action-based-on-selection-using-jquery/
         if (student.entry_year === entryYear){

             tableHTML +='<tr>\
                            <td>'+student.name+'</td>\
                            <td>'+student.entry_year+'</td>\
                          </tr>';
         } 
        }

        );//end each

        //close the table tag
        tableHTML += '</table>';

        // add the data pulled to the html of the page in the div dynamic table 
        $('#dynamicTable').html(tableHTML);
    });// end json
}

$(document).ready(function(){
          $.create_table(2017);

          $("select.year").change(function(){
              $.create_table($(this).children("option:selected").val());
           });

}); //end ready
```